# Проблема с MVC PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Есть такой код:
index.php :

```
<?php

// Подключаем загрузчик приложений в единую точку входа
require_once 'app/load.php';

?>
```

routing.php:

```
<?php
class Routing
{

    static function execute()
    {
        // контроллер и действие по умолчанию
        $controller_name = 'Main';
        $action_name = 'index';

        $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        $model_name = 'Model_'.$controller_name;
        $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
        $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;

        $controller_file = strtolower($controller_name).'.php';
        $controller_path = "core/".$controller_file;

        if(file_exists($controller_path))
        {
            include $controller_path;
        }

        // создаем контроллер
        $controller = new $controller_name;
        $action = $action_name;

    }

}
?>
```

load.php :

```
<?php

require_once 'core/routing.php';
require_once 'core/model.php';
require_once 'core/view.php';
require_once 'core/controller.php';
//Запуск роутинга
Routing::execute();

?>
```

controller.php:

```
<?php
class Controller {
    public $model;
    public $view;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this -> view = new View();
    }
}
?>
```

controller_main.php:

```
<?php

class Controller_Main extends Controller
{

    function action_index()
    {   
        $this -> view -> generate('fgdfgdfgdfg', 'template.php');
    }
}

?>
```

view.php:

```
<?php
class View
{
    function generate($content, $template, $data = null)
    {
        include 'app/views/template.php';
    }
}
?>
```

template.php:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Проблема в том, что непонятно, как правильно вывести на экран текст. Сейчас пусто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересно, а чего Вы хотели добиться, объявив экземпляр класса, но не обратившись к нему?)

```
$controller = new $controller_name;
$action = $action_name;
```

У Вас `$controller_name` - Ваш экземпляр `Controller_Main`, в котором лежит метод `action_index()`. Виюшка собирается, но не выводится, потому что Вы не обратились к этому методу. Можете в своем Routing написать в конце так `$controller -> $action();`

Да и второй `action_index()` в `class Controller` Вам зачем?

Comment: ``action_index()`` в class ``Controller`` лишнее. Сделал правку.